# Share a web page on LinkedIn keeps giving "Ooops! Its not you. Its us. Give it another try please" error page

Tags: linkedin-api, share, error-messaging

I have a web page that I am trying to share on LinkedIn but keep getting the same "Oops! Its not you..." error message.

The URL I am using for sharing is https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=[myURL] My URL is valid and works just fine when i run it through Post Inspector https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

All the necessary og tags are specified and I never had any issues sharing my pages through the above link before. I have already tried to talk to LinkedIn Helpdesk and was advised to ask here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello this is not the right place to ask this. Here it's for coding issues only. Try to ask super user or some dedicated LinkedIn forum. Meanwhile, retry in a couple hours. Try another url right now. If the other url works right now, it's linkedin that rejects your first share. Because any reason we will never know. Try to find the same content on another web page (rehosting), try to remove any jacascript from the url, etc. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This error message is actually a 100% generic error message from LinkedIn.  It displays when they have too much traffic and users try to login, look at news, post content, etc., etc..  According to [NewsWeek, 2019, March](https://www.newsweek.com/linkedin-outage-down-not-working-outage-oops-try-again-1370194)...

> Some LinkedIn users were reporting issues with the professional networking website on Wednesday. The issues were appearing on Down Detector and users were tweeting about the problems as well....
>
> Some users saw a message that said ***"We're getting things cleaned up. We'll be back soon,"*** while others saw a message that read, ***"Oops! It's not you. It's us. Give it another try, please."***

This seems to have been sometime before your post.  But it could be a likely cause.

If you're unsure, test your URL in the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/): this tool tells you how LinkedIn decides to build the preview for your website while sharing in LinkedIn.